# PowerShell script to search for text and a number greater than

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create a PowerShell script that searches output and looks for a number great than and sends an email. I'm currently using a script to search for text and send an email and that's working. But now I want it to search for text and a number that's greater than and send an email.

This is the current script:

```
 $Output = 'D:\test.data\QueuedJobss.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

        $MailArgs = @{
            'To'          = 'ab2112@test.com'
            'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
            'Subject'     = 'Media Server Offline!'
            'Attachments' = $Output
            'Body'        = 'Check NBU'

            'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.test.worldwide.com'
        }
        Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
    }
```

But now I want to have it search the following output:

```
Summary of jobs on ustestnbma01
Queued:                                1
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                           5
Successful:                   25876
Partially Successful:           136
Failed:                         327
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        26345
```

where it says `Queued: 1`. That's what I want searched and if it is greater than 50 send an email. Also, this output puts a lot of spaces after the word queued, is that a problem? If so, I can also have the output read as:

```
MASTER SERVER QUEUED REQUEUED ACTIVE SUCCESS PARTSUCC FAILED INCOMP SUSP 
ustestnbma01    1         0      4  25952     136      328      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a RegEx (capture group) into the pattern for Select-String.

```
$Output = 'D:\test.data\mediastatus.txt'
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\volmgr\bin'
.\vmoprcmd.exe > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value

if ($Queued -gt 50 ) {
    ## send email
}
```

- the -Pattern `"Queued\s+(\d+)"` where `\s+` represents at least one but as many as possible white space, `(\d+)` defines the capture group[1] containing at least one digit - but as many as possible.

Comment: `matches.groups[1].value` is coming back with cannot index into a null array full command looks like `$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: It looks like the search pattern is not found in output, I had the impression `Queued: 1` or an other number should always be present?

Comment: I changed it to `$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value` but now I don't think the -gt is working correctly. See updated code above. I am not getting anymore errors on the script but it's still not notifying me like it should when it's greater than a number. I know my send-mailmessage code is right because I use it everywhere.